# Docker create volume for MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, volume

I'm starting to use docker implement mysql in our environment. But I have a little bit confuse about it. 
1. I have tried to use command, it's working

```
sudo docker run --name mysql5.7 --restart always --privileged=true -p 4306:3006 -v /Users/user/mysql/config/mysqld.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf -v /Users/user/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_USER=“usr” -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=“1234” -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=“1234” -d mysql:5.7
```

2. But follow docker document, they suggest use volume to persist data. So I tried crate a volume first `docker volume -d create local mysql_v`
3. try to link mysql to volume mysql_v, but I don't know how to do it and what is different with step 1.

anyone can suggest it ~?

Comment: `mysql_v` is used instead of the source path `/Users/user/mysql/data`. Its empty, so maybe look if you need to migrated data.

Comment: hi danblack,  thank you for your reply. Actually I want to know how to attach mysql db and config to this volume? do you have any doc can share to me? or if say 1st step is create volume, what is next step so that mysql's config and data can attache to this volume? many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like

```
docker run --name mysql5.7 --restart always -p 4306:3006 \
     -v /Users/user/mysql/config/mysqld.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf \
     -v mysql_v:/var/lib/mysql \
     -e MYSQL_USER=“usr” -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=“1234” \
     -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=“1234” -d mysql:5.7
```

Note, privileged removed, that's just asking for trouble

Ref: [official documents](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-a-volume-using-a-volume-driver)